Elasticbeanstalk CloudFront REST API access denied NODE.js application
If i try to acces the REST API via my cloudfront URL i get the following error:
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>N49YQP8V1E2HES9A</RequestId>
<HostId>z6bywL8WiGhaQR+uEW14nEOh87xeh/wHhk5b5GCQZab5ZRre9eUz1iFmRuKXSpPP0HyJaAKhN4ovcxhw6mAwY0L1dWSj3149</HostId>
</Error>

If i access the elastic beanstalk url through the aws url it gives me the correct json back
{server is running}

In the console its a 403 error i already changed the corse setting in the s3 bucket aswell as the bucket policy .Also i am using a single instance to save costs and not a balance loader.
I did also try to use the OAI as mentioned in some already answered question but nothing is working.
Did anyone else maybe hosted his own REST API with those tools and maybe came accross the same error?
I expect my API to give me the correct json file back.

I tried even more but concluded that this is probably not possible without a load balancer. Therefore, if anyone sees this, the quickest and cheapest way is to use an EC2 Ubuntu instance and host everything via EC2.
